# Filtering rows based on relation of cells value - GS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

My goal is filter all rows of one Google Sheet which contains an especific value "ELB" in column "STATUS PEP". But I also want to filter the rows that contains the same value of the column "PROJETO". In other words, filter all group of rows that has the same value in column "PROJETO" and has at least one line of each group with the value "ELB" in the column "STATUS PEP".

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nE3B.png) The image can explain better. All the yellow highlighted rows must be filter, because has de same value (A) and at least one value "ELB" (B). None of the others rows has the last condition.

I will appreciate any ideia.

I´ve tried to create a formula to automate this filter or to flag the rows than I can use a simple GS filter. I have no ideia how to do this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter((r,i) => {
    if(i>0) {
      if(r[1] == "ELB" && r[4] == vs[i - 1][4]) {
        return r;
      }
    }
  }).filter(e => e);
  return vs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cooper for your code. But I could not find a good source to explain how the code works. Sorry for my dummies level. Also, in this part ' ==vs[1-1][4] ' 1-1 seems to be always the same results, so why not 0 in place of 1-1. If you could clarify a little bit, or give a link I could study more about the use of FILTER function.

Comment: Probably [i - 1]

Comment: Sorry I left some things out.  I would have caught them when I ran it the first time but of course I have no data.

Comment: No problem, it´s ok.